# Writing in text editor at line 5

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
1 1 1 \n
1 1 2  \n
1 1 3  \n
1 2 1  \n
1 2 2  \n
1 2 3  \n
1 3 1  \n
1 3 2  \n
```

I want to save each line in a new text file. I've developed the code already but this saves each line at the beginning of the text file.

I want to save each line of the master text file separately in a new file but at a specific line and column.

For example `1 1 1` should be in a new file [a1.text] at line 5 and colmn 10. `1 1 2` should be in a new file [a2.text] at line 4 column 10.

How can edit the code? |T tried different methods, using seek, writelines, insert but I am confused because maybe I am mixing pathlib with os.

I also have tried seek, insert. but may be i am not doing it write.

```
from pathlib import *

z= Path ('Desktop/pythonfiles/a.DATA').read_text().splitlines ()
for i in z:
        print (i , file= open ('c:/Users/Muhammad Ali/Desktop/python files/'+i+'.DATA', 'w'))
```

Result:

> 1 1 1 saving in a newfile (a1.text) at Line 5, column 20 1 1 2 saving
>   in a newfile (a2.text) at line 6, column 20

Comment: please if any one can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly read the text file as liens using readlines() method then loop over the lines printing each line in a new file while formatting the file name with an incrementing counter, as follows:

```
data = open('source.txt','r').readlines()
file_num = 1
for line in data:
    open('a{}.txt'.format(file_num),'w').write(line)
    file_num+=1
```